# compare two language html pages and create a mapping

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, parsing

I am doing a research to compare two different sites (one in English and other one is in Spanish. However, both sites have same HTML structure) and trying to create a dictionary for the sentences in English to Spanish for the HTML elements. 
Can someone suggest me the best way to achieve this?
Here is the example code sniplet:

```html
ENglish:
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Welcome</Title></HEAD>
<BODY><DIV class="a">hello</Div></BODY>
<HTML>

Spanish:
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Welcome</Title></HEAD>
<BODY><DIV class="a">¡Hola</Div></BODY>
<HTML>

Output Expected: hello -> ¡Hola
```

Can you please suggest me tools or Apis  that can help me to do this?
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Very specific, you may need a good algorithm there...

Comment: *"4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."* - [On-Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: If the DOM's are identical except for the text content, you could use a query selector to grab all text nodes of both DOM's. identical DOM = identical indexed result of queries.

Comment: Can't you parse the html find the html element at same level in another page and store the text in it.